# Explanation of Racket function using map, append, and a recursive call

Tags: racket

This procedure takes a non-negative integer n and creates a list of all lists of n 0's or 1's in the specific order required for a truth table. I am just trying to understand how the map portion of the procedure works. I am particularly confused as to how append, map, and the recursive call to all-lists are working together in the second argument of the if. Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated!

```
(define all-lists
  (lambda (n)
    (if (= n 0)
      '(())
      (append (map (lambda (k) (cons 0 k)) (all-lists (- n 1)))
              (map (lambda (k) (cons 1 k)) (all-lists (- n 1)))
              ))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best strategy to understand a recursive function is to try it with the case sligthly more complex than the terminal one. So, let's try it with `n=1`.

In this case, the function becomes:

```
(append (map (lambda (k) (cons 0 k)) (all-lists 0))
        (map (lambda (k) (cons 1 k)) (all-lists 0))
```

that is:

```
(append (map (lambda (k) (cons 0 k)) '(()))
        (map (lambda (k) (cons 1 k)) '(())))
```

So, the first `map` applies the function `(lambda (k) (cons 0 k))` to all the elements of the list `'(()))`, which has only an element, `'()`, producing `'((0))` (the list containing an element obtained by the `cons` of `0` and the empty list), and in the same way the second map produces `'((1))`.
These lists are appended together yielding the list `'((0) (1))`, in other words, the list of all the lists of length 1 with all the possible combinations of `0` and `1`.

In the case of `n=2`, the recursive case is applied to `'((0) (1))`: so the first map puts a `0` before all the elements, obtaining `'((0 0) (0 1))`, while the second map produces `'((1 0) (1 1))`. If you append together these two lists, you obtain `'((0 0) (0 1) (1 0) (1 1))`, which is the list of all the possible combinations, of length 2, of `0` and `1`.

And so on, and so on...

Actually, the function is not well defined, since it calculates unnecessarily the value of `(all-lists (- n 1))` two times at each recursion, so doubling its work, which is already exponential. So it could be made much more efficient by computing that value only once, for instance in the following way:

```
(define all-lists
  (lambda (n)
    (if (= n 0)
        '(())
        (let ((a (all-lists (- n 1))))
          (append (map (lambda (k) (cons 0 k)) a)
                  (map (lambda (k) (cons 1 k)) a))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Separating statements along with 'println' can help understand what is happening:

```
(define (all-lists n)
    (if (= n 0)
        '(())
        (let* ((a (all-lists (- n 1)))
               (ol1 (map (λ (k) (cons 0 k)) a))
               (ol2 (map (λ (k) (cons 1 k)) a))
               (ol (append ol1 ol2)))
          (println "---------")
          (println ol1)
          (println ol2)
          (println ol)
          ol)))

(all-lists 3)
```

Output:

```
"---------"
'((0))
'((1))
'((0) (1))
"---------"
'((0 0) (0 1))
'((1 0) (1 1))
'((0 0) (0 1) (1 0) (1 1))
"---------"
'((0 0 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 0) (0 1 1))
'((1 0 0) (1 0 1) (1 1 0) (1 1 1))
'((0 0 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 0) (0 1 1) (1 0 0) (1 0 1) (1 1 0) (1 1 1))
'((0 0 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 0) (0 1 1) (1 0 0) (1 0 1) (1 1 0) (1 1 1))
```

One can clearly see how outlists (ol1, ol2 and combined ol) are changing at each step.